# How to apply a seperate texture to each side of a plane? (Blender Render)

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

So I've got a two-sided texture that works fine on a plane (Here I've made it a cloth) in Cycles render. However, I was curious on how to do this in the Blender Render?[image: There is a brick on one side of the plane and metal on the other]

[image: I have no idea how to do this in Blender Render]

Blender Render works completely differently to Cycles and if I were able to use a two-sided texture plane in Blender Render it would be a huge help!

Comment: Did you try duplicating the object then flipping it normals and applying a different material?

Comment: If I duplicate the object would that not mean I have two different cloths which will overlap and create texture artifices as they clip into one another?

Comment: I think so. Try it on a simpler scene ans see if it works